# Facebook how to get support for: Stream Stories Restricted: Stream stories are restricted for this application

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

We have an app that has been flagged as spam and now we have a stream stories restricted error on a publish action.

What are the ways to contact FB to let them recheck the application to recover from this restriction? They have changed the whole help center and I can't find any useful info.

Has someone got into this problem? How did you manage to solve it?

Thanks.
Simone

Comment: After some research I found out that there's an appeal section in the developer center (https://developers.facebook.com/appeal). I followed the instructions provided here: https://www.facebook.com/help/155308851202619
Let's see if this works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For info, that was the way to go:

- after each action from FB you should receive a notificatiion with all the info in it.
- if for some reason (like in my case) you haven't received the notification you can follow this link: http://developers.facebook.com/appeal and do everything from there